# LWC problem to save or deploy

Tags: salesforcedx

Today I have a problem with my vscode, I can't deploy my lwc or save it, only show me a message error but it is empty.

[image]

I try to uninstall vscode, extensions or updating sfdx without any solution.

Comment: I see that you're using the beta feature for enhanced deployments, I linked another answer with the details about disabling that feature, which has some deployment issues. (I didn't want to just duplicate my other answer here)

Comment: Thank you Mark, finally I can solve it.